# PHP linkify string email, @user, #hash and http://

Tags: php, regex, string

What is best way to convert string:

```
 This is example string from @user@user2 with email user@domain.com and hash #user#user2 from link http://domain.com
```

in this way:

```
 This is example string from <a href="/user">@user</a><a href="/user2">@user2</a> with email <a href="mailto:user@domain.com">user@domain.com</a> and hash <a href="/tag/user/">#user</a><a href="/tag/user2/">#user2</a> from link <a href="http://domain.com">http://domain.com</a>
```

with php?
I need simple function like this:

```
function convert($str)
{
    //regex...
    return $str;
}
```

Tnx.

Comment: Excellent. You're on the right track, let's see your regexp attempts. This is not a code for free service.

Comment: Regex or simple string replacements would do it... Try !